# The meaning of pass over in this sentence

Tags: phrases

I am having difficulty understanding the meaning of "passed over" in this sentence. and not sure who's doing the action of "passing over"? Can I get a little help please? thanks.

> "Burden of Truth is a legal drama starring Kristin Kreuk as a big city
> lawyer passed over for partnership who returns to her hometown to take
> on what she thinks is a simple case, only to find herself in a fight
> for justice for a group of sick girls."

Comment: They could have appointed her but they appointed someone else.

Comment: The senior members of her firm have recently _passed her over_ (not made her a partner when she had been expecting that they would).

Answer (score 1):

> ... lawyer passed over for partnership ...

> ... who's doing the action of "passing over"?

Partners are senior members in a law firm.  People with the authority to evaluate such candidates may be the "managing partners", who are [the highest officials of the firm. These consist of senior-level lawyers or founders of the firm.](https://www.zippia.com/answers/what-is-law-firm-hierarchy/)

To answer your question, these are likely the people who did the passing over.

[**Pass over** is a phrasal verb](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pass-over)

> PHRASAL VERB [usually passive]

> If someone is **passed over** for a job or position, they do not get the job or position and someone younger or less experienced is chosen instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means that a person that was her junior was promoted and became her senior.

Here she was in a position to become a partner in the law firm, this is usually the most senior position in a legal company.  But she didn't get the promotion, instead someone who was her junior became partner.

It is unfortunately still common for women to get passed over.  Some may choose to resign rather than work for a company that doesn't recognise their ablities.

I suppose it is the person who is promoted who is the implicit subject, but that person isn't to blame. It is the company that promoted them. The fact that the subject isn't important here is a good reason to use a passive voice.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! The score of that answer was - 1.Now is 0.Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!